# PowerShell Compare two Multidimensional Arrays to make a single Multidimensional Array that contains rows that were duplicates

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

I have $array1 =  ["ID","Name","Brand","State","created_by","approved_by","date"] generated in first foreach  loop then two minutes later in a second foreach loop another is generated $array2 =  ["ID","Name","Brand","State","created_by","approved_by","date"].  Now doing a compare if $array1 and $array2 both contain an ID / Name , use this duplication to create the new $array3 - and exclude the entries in $array1 that did not reoccur in $array2.

How do you do the PowerShell compare and include only the duplicate rows from both arrays to create the 3rd array?

here's code I'm working with:
##The first array

$exportObjectA=@()
ForEach ($row in $dataset.Tables[0].Rows) {

```
    $ExciterObject = New-Object PSObject
    $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date Created" -Value $row.created_date
    $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Location" -Value $row.Location 
    $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Exciter Name" -Value $row.exciter_name 
    $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Exciter ID" -Value $row.ExciterID
    $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Reason Down" -Value $row.ReasonDown
    $exportObjectA += $ExciterObject

    }
```

###The second array

$exportObjectB=@()
ForEach ($row in $dataset.Tables[0].Rows) {

```
            $ExciterObject = New-Object PSObject
            $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date Created" -Value $row.created_date
            $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Location" -Value $row.Location 
            $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Exciter Name" -Value $row.exciter_name 
            $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Exciter ID" -Value $row.ExciterID
            $ExciterObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Reason Down" -Value $row.ReasonDown
            $exportObjectB += $ExciterObject

            }


$exportObjectA | ForEach-Object {
    if ($exportObjectB -contains $_) {
        Write-Host "`$exportObjectB contains the 
`$exportObjectA$row.exciter_name string [$_]"
    }
```

}

Comment: Both arrays look the same to me. `Compare-Object` can compare properties across different collections. You can also use `Group-Object`.

Comment: so if you have $array1 that contains 3 rows - with repeatable Name value Harris in $array2.  In $array3 you would have the row containing Name=Harris and its relative data.  This would be the opposite of Get-Unique.  This script is query a database twice within a four minute period - if an event occurs twice add added to the new array - that will be used to report out events that are still happening.

Comment: So either name or ID duplicated will go to array3? Or does both name and ID need to match?

Comment: so if the row containing Harris appears in both arrays - and any other row that has a name appearing twice in $array1 and $array2 will be in the new $array3.  The key is the name value because the database query will have unique IDs.

Comment: So you want something like `$array3 = $array1 |Where{$_.Name -in $array2.Name}; $array3 += $array2 |Where($_.Name -in $array1.Name}` then? That builds `$array3` out of the items in `$array1` that have items in `$array2` with the same Name, then adds the items from `$array2` based on the same criteria. Sound right?

Comment: yes TheMadTechnician - here's some clips from my code.  Its basically querying the database to twice before making a decision to email our support team an event has occurred.  Don't want to wake them up if it self healed.